# How Access instance Variable in Class method

Tags: objective-c

I am a new iOS developer, i try to access instance variable in class method but i can't access.please give me some solution here is my code

h.file

```
@protocol ServiceProvideDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)responeFromURL:(NSDictionary*)dicResponse;
@end

@interface AFNetworkServiceProvider : NSObject
{
   id <ServiceProvideDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;

+(NSDictionary*)getResponseFromURL:(NSURL*)url;
@end
```

m.file

```
@implementation AFNetworkServiceProvider
@synthesize delegate;
+(void)getResponseFromURL:(NSURL *)url
{
 @try
 {
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        if(delegate)
        {
          [delegate responeFromURL:responseObject]
       } 
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response Error :- %@",[error localizedDescription] );
    }];
    [requestOperation start];    
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{

}
@finally {

}
}
```

Try to Returne Response object using protocol method, but i get the error at if(delegate) unable to access instance variable in class method

Comment: So where in this code are you trying to access the instance variable? What code is it that is failing?

Comment: You can't access an instance variable in a class method - no instance exists.

Comment: Ah, I see your question (you've titled it completely wrong) - You can't return data from an `asynchronous` operation, you have to use a callback

Comment: @Hiren: You should ask your "return dictionary from block" as a separate question (@Adam addresses that above).

Comment: Thank Adam and Ben Zotton for your Response

Comment: I know that i can't return data from an asynchronous operation but is it any other way yo Do Adam. Adam can you pls explain about callback and how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and that's an intentional part of the design. For a given class, you can create as many instances of it as you want, but each is independent, and each has its own set of state (variables/properties).

A class method doesn't carry state, and doesn't know about any of the instances, so it can't know *which* instance's variables you want access to.

I assume you want access to the `delegate`. Perhaps your method should be an instance method instead here?

Comment: Yes @ben I try to access delegate. Thank for your response.i understand from your answer that i have to use instances method